# openGL GLSL understanding vertext array Object

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, vertex-shader

I am trying to understand the code for `sierpinski gasket`. This is some rough code:

**headers and constants**

```
#include "Angel.h"

const int NumPoints = 5000;
```

**init()**

```
void init(void)
{
    vec2 points[NumPoints];

    // Specifiy the vertices for a triangle
    vec2 vertices[3] = {
        vec2(-1.0, -1.0), vec2(0.0, 1.0), vec2(1.0, -1.0)
    };

    // Select an arbitrary initial point inside of the triangle
    points[0] = vec2(0.25, 0.50);

    // compute and store N-1 new points
    for (int i = 1; i < NumPoints; ++i) {
        int j = rand() % 3;   // pick a vertex at random

        // Compute the point halfway between the selected vertex
        //   and the previous point
        points[i] = (points[i - 1] + vertices[j]) / 2.0;
        
        // CITS3003 Lab1 q1circle: Added the following two lines (and nothing
        // else)
        if (length(points[i]) > 1.0)
          i--;

 // Create a vertex array object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create and initialize a buffer object
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader("vshader.glsl", "fshader.glsl");
    glUseProgram(program);

    // Initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); // white background
    }
```

I understand the first half of the code. We are creating a vector array that stores vectors of size 2 (x,y) of size 5000. Then we are creating a vertices array that stores the first triangle, i.e. its 3 vertices in the screen space (-1,1) range. The randomly, we are choosing a vertex and the current point and finding the midpoint of that and using the next current point for the next loop, and so on.

The confusing part is the next bit. We are creating a vertex array object. I don't quite understand the point of this, which firstly i have no idea what's happening, and secondly why `vao` is even used when we don't give it anything.

Similar with the buffer.

Could anyone give a quick rundown of what is happening?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object

Comment: The question is to broad. Explaining the OpenGL Vertex specification generally fills one chapter of a book. Read about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [LearnOpenGL - Hello Triangle](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sorry if it is a bit broad. What i am tyring to get at is the 3 line of code where we make the vector array what is happening there.